# Receiving Data from Machine using Socket

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets

I am very new in Socket Programming. 
I am using the following code to receive incoming data from a pathology machine.

```
 byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(SERVER_IP);
        IPEndPoint localEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, PORT_NO);

        Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        try
        {
            sock.Connect(localEndpoint);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        while (true)
        {                
            int bytesRec = sock.Receive(buffer);
            data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRec);
            if (data.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Issues I am facing

1. Machine is sending huge amount of data and gets buys and disconnects from program after some time.
2. How can I start receiving data again ? Is there any receiving event which fires automatically for incoming data?
   What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You created buffer, its Length property is always whatever size you gave it (2048). The `Receive()` method returns the number of bytes read from the socket so do something like var bytesRead = sock.Receive(buffer); test(bytesRead); use(buffer, bytesRead);`

Comment: @AlanK I have already done here `while ((recv = sock.Receive(buffer)) > 0)`

Comment: You need to know the framing format of what you're expecting. The machine sending you the data must have a way of framing the data. You need to use this framing to create your read requirements.

Comment: I posted a detailed answer. Check my response

Answer (score 4):

There's a few things here;

1. you need to *store* the read count, and use *only that many bytes*, i.e. `var bytes = sock.Receive(buffer);` (and use `bytes` for both the EOF test, and for how many bytes to process)
2. we can't use `ToString().Length > 1` here, because it is an integer and *every* integer, as a string, has a non-zero length; instead, simply: `if (bytes > 0)` (minutiae: there *is* a scenario where an open socket can return zero without meaning EOF, but... it doesn't apply here)
3. even for a text protocol, you can't *necessarily* simply use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes)`, because UTF8 is a multi-byte encoding, meaning: you might have partial characters; additionally, you don't yet know whether that is one message, half a message, or 14 and a bit messages; you need to read about the protocol's "framing" - which might simply mean "buffer bytes until you see a newline (`'\n'`) character, decode *those buffered bytes via the encoding*, process that message, and repeat"

Comment: I have opened my question again with some edit. Can you please help.

Comment: Marc can you help me please?

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi sockets die; I can't diagnose much more than that without seeing a repro or at least more details of what you're seeing

Answer (score 0):

## Problem Analysis

Your medical pathology machine stops sending packets to your **C#** application because it does not have anything to send. Your pathology machine will send information only when it has data that is being processed.

## Solution Rationale

Due to the fact that you can never know when the machine within the medical laboratory will be set by the technicians to run any analysis you must set your **C#** application to operate in a ***waiting for response*** state. This means that your application must operate like a **deamon** or **service** and be ready to receive packets from the specified machine in order to process them at any time.

## Solution

The problem within your code may seem that, as others pointed out, you read the data from the server expecting it to be a fixed length. So, if the pathology machine sends **3000 bytes** of data and you read **2048 bytes** there are **952 bytes** that are discarded. Another issue with your code is that once you read the data, your socket will disconnect from the server and the program will shutdown. In order to solve the aforementioned issue you must try connect to the server continuously in order to see if the server has any payload to send.

To demonstrate this I made a server application that sends packets every 5 seconds and that will drop any connection made that is not made within that timeframe, and I also made a client application that will try to connect to the server continuously and read all the data sent by the server without knowing the dimension of the payload to be received.

### Server code

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace Socket_Server
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            // INITIATE THE SERVER OPERATION
            ServerOperation();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        // METHOD THAT IS HANDLING EACH CLIENT ASYNCHRONOUSLY;
        private static async void ServerOperation()
        {

            // SERVER SOCKET THAT IS USING THE IP PROTOCOL, USING THE IPv4 IP PROTOCOL, AND 
            // THAT IS ALLOWING THE INFORMATION TO BE SENT TO THE CLIENT AND RECEIVED FROM
            // THE CLIENT 
            Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);

            // SERVER WILL LISTEN TO THE MACHINE'S LOOPBACK ADDRESS ('127.0.0.1') AT PORT 80
            server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 80));

            // SERVER WILL WAIT FOR THE INFORMATION TO BE RECEIVED BY THE CLIENT 1000 MILLISECONDS BEFORE SHUTING THE
            // CONNECTION DOWN.
            server.ReceiveTimeout = 10000;

            // SERVER WILL WAIT FOR THE INFORMATION TO BE SENT BY THE CLIENT 1000 MILLISECONDS BEFORE SHUTING THE
            // CONNECTION DOWN.
            server.SendTimeout = 10000;

            // SERVER WILL HANDLE 1000 CONNECTIONS, EACH CONNECTION AFTER WILL BE PUT IN A WAIT FOR RESPONSE STATE
            server.Listen(1000);

            Console.WriteLine("!!! SERVER RUNNING !!!");



            // SAVE THE CURRENT DATE AND TIME WHEN THE OPERATION WAS INITIATED 
            DateTime timeout = DateTime.Now;

            // SIMULATE A PACKET TRANSFER EVERY 5 SECONDS
            while(true)
            {
                // IF THE AMOUNT OF TIME ELAPSED BETWEEN THE INITIAL
                // TIME AND CURRENT TIME IS GREATER THAN 5 SECONDS 
                if((DateTime.Now - timeout).TotalSeconds >= 5)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ClientOperation(await server.AcceptAsync());
                        // RESET THE INITAL TIME
                        timeout = DateTime.Now;
                    }
                    catch{}
                }
            }
        } 


        // SIMULATE A PACKET TRANSFER EVERY 5 SECONDS
        private async static void ClientOperation(Socket client){
            try
            {
                // MESSAGE TO BE SENT
                string message = @"<BOF>In the realm where science meets life's intricate design, 
                                   Pathology machines stand as beacons, divine. With precision and grace, 
                                   they unravel the unknown, Unveiling the secrets that lie deep in our bones.<EOF>"; 

                // MESSAGE TO BE SENT ENCODED AS BYTES IN UTF8 STRING FORMAT
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message); 

                // SEND THE BYTES TO THE CLIENT
                int sent = await client.SendAsync(buffer);
                Console.WriteLine("Sent: " + sent);
            }
            catch{}
        }
    }
}
```

### Client code

```
namespace Socket_Client
{
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Text;

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            // INITIATE THE CLIENT OPERATION
            ClientOperation();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async void ClientOperation()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("!!! CLIENT LISTENING !!!");

            int count = 0;

            while(true)
            {
                // CLIENT SOCKET THAT IS USING THE IP PROTOCOL, USING THE IPv4 IP PROTOCOL, AND 
                // THAT IS READING THE INFORMATION SENT BY THE SERVER
                Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
                try
                {


                    // CLIENT WILL WAIT FOR THE INFORMATION TO BE RECEIVED BY THE CLIENT 1000 MILLISECONDS BEFORE SHUTING THE
                    // CONNECTION DOWN.
                    client.ReceiveTimeout = 10000;

                    // CLIENT WILL WAIT FOR THE INFORMATION TO BE SENT BY THE CLIENT 1000 MILLISECONDS BEFORE SHUTING THE
                    // CONNECTION DOWN.
                    client.SendTimeout = 10000;
                    
                    // CLIENT WILL CONNETC TO THE SERVER THAT IS RUNNING LOCALLY 
                    // AT THE MACHINE'S LOOPBACK ADDRESS ('127.0.0.1') AT PORT 80
                    await client.ConnectAsync(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 80));

                    // START THE PACKAGE EXTRACTION OPERATION
                    string result = ClientSessionOperation(client);


                    // INCREMENT THE TOTAL NUMBER OF PAYLOADS RECEIVED
                    count++;


                    Console.WriteLine("Count: " + count);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n" + result + "\n\n");
                }
                catch
                {

                }
                finally
                {
                    // IF EITHER THE OPERATION SUCEEDS OR FAILS, DISPOSE THE CLIENT SOCKET
                    client?.Dispose();
                }
            }
           
        }

        // PAYLOAD EXTRACTION OPERATION
        private static string ClientSessionOperation(Socket client)
        {
            // STRING BUFFER THAT STORES THE PAYLOAD RESULT
            string result = String.Empty;

            // BYTE LIST THAT STORES THE PAYLOAD 
            List<byte> payload = new List<byte>();
            try
            {
                // WRAP THE "Socket" OBJECT IN A "NetworkStream" OBJECT
                // TO BE ABLE TO READ BYTES PIECE BY PIECE FROM THE
                // PAYLOAD SENT BY THE SERVER
                NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(client);

                // WHILE BYTES ARE AVAILABLE FOR READ WITHIN 
                // THE CONNECTION'S STREAM
                while(stream.CanRead == true)
                {
                    // READ BYTE
                    int recv_byte = stream.ReadByte();

                    // IF THE BYTE RECEIVED IS NOT A TERMINATOR BYTE
                    if(recv_byte != -1)
                    {
                        // APPEND THE RECEIVED BYTE IN THE LIST THAT CONTAINS
                        // THE PAYLOAD IN A BINARY FORMAT
                        payload.Add((byte)recv_byte);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }

            // IF THE NUMBER OF BYTES WITHIN THE LIST THAT CONTAINS
            // THE PAYLOAD IN A BINARY FORMAT IS GREATER THAN 0
            if(payload.Count > 0)
            {
                // CONVERT THE LIST TO A BYTE ARRAY AND SUBSEQUENTLY
                // CONVERT THE AFOREMENTIONED LIST IN A STRING THAT
                // IS ENCODED IN THE "UTF8" FORMAT
                result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(payload.ToArray());
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

### Result

[image: Animated GIF that shows the programs running]